# Getting malformed output in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

have a data file that I read in in my Shiny server function. I would like to display a frequency table of the two columns the user selects using drop-downs. I get the error "table of extent 0". I have looked at R error - Table of extent 0 and Can't solve table issue but I have imported my data correctly and the column names match as well. The same line of code works when I run it in the console.

Here is my code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$courseData = renderTable( {


    data = read.csv(file = 'FourCourseTableLetterGrades_POLISHED.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
    c1 = input$course1
    c2 = input$course2
    tbl = table(data[[c1]], data[[c2]])
    tbl

 }

)
}

)
```

This is how the output looks right now:

[image: screenshot]

I would like it to be like the output you get when you run the same code in console. Like so:

[image]

What is wrong with my code? Also, I don't know where names `Var1`, `Var2`, and `Freq` come from and where I should change them.

Answer (score 0):

`renderTable` will change any input to a dataframe before sending it to the UI, so you end up with something like `data.frame(table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$gear))`. We can try

```
output$courseData = renderTable(rownames=TRUE, {
data = mtcars
c1 = input$course1
c2 = input$course2
tbl = as.data.frame.matrix(table(data[[c1]], data[[c2]]))
tbl})
}
```

Comment: Better thanks, can we also add the column names and make it more beautiful? Like a colored confusion matrix?